# oMath - Comment an Equation in Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

Hi I need to program to add comments in certain situation, in my static test it completes the code but also gives a Type Mismatch error at the end. How should I amend this please?

```
Sub EquTest()

Dim objRange As range
Dim objEq As OMath
 
Set objRange = Selection.range
objRange.Text = "Celsius = (5/9)(Fahrenheit - 32)"
Set objRange = Selection.OMaths.Add(objRange)

Set objEq = objRange.OMaths(1)
objEq.BuildUp
Set objEq = objEq.range.Comments.Add(Selection.range, "Blah Blah") 
'Comment added but then Type mismatch displayed

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.Comments.Add` returns a comment, not the OMath object that `objEq` is expecting. Also you don't need to use the `Selection` more than once

```
Sub EquTest()

    Dim objRange As Range
    Dim objEq As OMath
 
    Set objRange = Selection.Range
    objRange.Text = "Celsius = (5/9)(Fahrenheit - 32)"
    Set objRange = objRange.OMaths.Add(objRange)

    Set objEq = objRange.OMaths(1)
    objEq.BuildUp
    'method 1 - if all you need to do is add the comment
    objEq.Range.Comments.Add objRange, "Blah Blah"
    'method 2 - if you need to do more with the comment once it has been added
    With objEq.Range.Comments.Add(objRange, "Blah Blah")
    
    End With
    'method 3 - alternative to method 2
    Dim cmt As Comment
    Set cmt = objEq.Range.Comments.Add(objRange, "Blah Blah")
End Sub
```